# use array in javascript foreach

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, foreach, json

I have the following  (simplified) php function which calculates a total value for me. it basically fetch an array of items from the wordpress database and checks the type of each item and then compare its value to a specific given value and sums all the comparisons up.

```
        function total(){ 
        $value1 = 10; // compare value for type 1 items
        $value1 = 20; // type 2 items
        $value1 = 30; // type 3 items
        $total = 0; // reset total variable

global $wpdb;
        $items = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `item_type` as type, `item_value` as value FROM `table`"); // get all the items from database

        foreach ($items as $item) {

    // check which item type
        switch ($item->type) { 
          case 1:
         $total = $total + min($value1, $item->value);
            break;
          case 2:
          $total = $total + min($value2, $item->value);
            break;
          case 3:
         $total = $total + min($value3, $item->value);
            break;
        }}

        return $total;
        }
```

Now i want to remake the same function in javascript so i can use it in a form for calculations. This is what i got so far;

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
 function calculate_total (){
    var items = <?php echo json_encode($items); ?>;
    var value1 = document.form.range1Input.value;
    var value2 = document.form.range2Input.value;
    var value3 = document.form.range3Input.value;

  for each (var item in items){
     switch (**(refer to item type in array)**) { 
          case 1:
         total = total + min(value1, **(refer to item value in array)**);
            break;
          case 2:
          total = total + min(value2, **(refer to item value in array)**);
            break;
          case 3:
         total = total + min(value3, **(refer to item value in array)**);
            break;
        }}

 document.form.total.value = total;
}
</script>
```

How can i refer to the values in the items array? I hope somebody can give me some advice on this one.

Also i saw that `echo json_encode($items)` formats the array as `{"type":"3","value":"1.00"},{"type":"1","value":"20.50"}` etc etc, I was wondering if this is a usable format for javascript because when i try `total = items[1];` I see `[Object Object]` in the form.

`$items = $pdb->get_results()` is btw formatted as `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [type] => 1 [value] => 35.00 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [type] => 3 [value] => 1.00 )`

Comment: what does it look like in the javascript side? what is item on the first loop?

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure what do you mean? I have little to no experience with javascript

Comment: i mean when you send it from php to javascript what does the data look like? what does `items` contain.. is it json? an array? can you put that up too ? thanks :)

Comment: Try `total = items[1].value` instead of `total = items[1];`

Comment: print_r(items$) = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [type] => 1 [value] => 35.00 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [type] => 3 [value] => 1.00 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [type] => 1 [value] => 20.50 ) etc etc

Comment: @mikach he thanks man, that gives me the actual content of the array! Can you tell me how i can use this in the for each statement ?

Comment: i was asking what it was like in the javascript side.. not the php side.. but its an array since items[1].value works

Comment: Hmmm i'm only receiving the item values from the arrays and not the types. I tried items[0][1].value but it doesn't gave any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you speculated, your first item can be referred to as `items[0]`, second as `items[1]`, and so on.

So, in your `switch` statement / within your for loop where `item` refers to the current index (0, 1, 2, etc), you can say `items[item]` to refer to the item you're currently looking at in your loop: first it will be equal to `items[0]`, then `items[1]`, and so on.

So, `switch (items[item].type) {` should be what you need.

---

(A quick JS recap: arrays and objects are different things in JS, look up the differences if you're not sure. When referencing them, you can use `myArray[0]` to get things from an array, and you can use `myObject['myKey']` or `myObject.myKey` to get things from an object. In your case, `items` is an **array**, and each of its elements is an **object**. You can therefore do `items[0]['type']` or `items[0].type` to access the type of your first item).

---

The reason `items[1]` just showed `[Object object]` when you tried it is because browsers aren't great at displaying objects on screen – the object is there, and JS can see it, it's just that most objects are printed as `[Object object]`. You'd be better off displaying `JSON.stringify(items[1])` to see a JSON representation of the object as a string. Better yet, try `console.log(items)` or `console.log(items[1])` to see the entire object in your browser's *console* (you can search for how to bring up your browser console, it's different for each browser/OS, but it's brilliant for debugging).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read up on your JavaScript syntax, but there are four ways to loop over an array:

TL;DR: if you're doing things that mutate state, I recommend `Array#forEach`, if not, recommend `Array#map`.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var len = myArray.length;
```

1) for loop

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
  doSomethingTo(myArray[i]);
}
```

2) while loop

```
var i = 0; 
while (i<len) {
  doSomethingTo(myArray[i]);
  i++;
}
```

3) forEach

```
myArray.forEach(function (element) {
  doSomethingTo(element);
});
```

4) map

```
var newArray = myArray.map(function (element) {
  doSomethingTo(element);
});
```

Of these four, ONLY `map` has a return. It will run the function you give it on each of the elements of the array, and return an array of those all together. the `while` loop is the fastest, but you should avoid doing things imperatively like that if you can.

Comment: Hi Moshe, thanks for this information! Can you be somewhat more specific how i can use this for my case? Any directions would help :)